# How to execute multiple executables with a pattern in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Lets say there are a few executables.

```
ATest, BTest, CTest, random1, random2
```

I want to execute everything that ends with "Test", but I do not know beforehand exactly how many executable fits this criteria

```
./*Test
```

only ends up executing the ATest

but something like

```
ls *Test
```

works perfectly showing only the files ending with Test.

What is the correct shell command to execute multiple executables with a pattern without knowing how much files matches this pattern?

Comment: It sounds like you want to start using a test harness. There are a couple of solutions out there (and they also help with reporting the results).

Comment: You can use `ls` if the executable filenames don't contain white spaces like `ls *Test | xargs -n1 -I {} ./{}`. If they do contain white paces you may use `find` as `find . -name \*Test -print0|xargs -0 -n1 -I{} {}`. They will be executed one after the other. If you prefer to execute them all at once, run them in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a short script to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *Test
do
 "./$f"
done
```

Or, even as a one-liner:

```
for f in *Test; do "./$f"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name \*Test -exec  ./{} \;
```

EDIT: This will also search all subdirectories. To only search current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*Test -exec  ./{} \;
```

Comment: This gives me an "find: paths must precede expression: ATest" error

Comment: I believe if you put double quotes around *Test this will work

Comment: hmm, I tested it on bash, and it works for me. Which shell are you using?

Comment: @BuddyYaussy I tested this on bash and it didn't work without the quotes

Comment: Sorry, when I copy/pasted from my terminal window, this web site ignored my backslash before the *. Edited to correct.

Comment: This doesn't account for matches found in subdirectories (which it searches too).

Comment: +1 Nice fix. `find` also has `-execdir` which would make the first example work with the whole tree (if that's desirable).